# Do the Raphael Rooms need a separate ticket?

Tags: italy, rome, vatican-city

I thought the Raphael Rooms, Sphere within a Sphere and Cortile della Pigna, were all part of the Vatican Museums.

That is, they do not need any special tickets. I thought they are all included in the Vatican  Museums ticket.

But there is conflicting information online that seems to say that these need separate tickets.

Is it true ? Do they all need separate tickets ?

https://www.tripadvisor.com/AttractionProductReview-g187793-d13330947-Skip_the_Line_Vatican_Museum_Sistine_Chapel_Raphael_Rooms_Basilica_Access-Vatican_.html

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Please copy the text out of the picture into text, in the answer.

Comment: According to https://visitvatican.info/raphael-rooms/ entry is included in the basic ticket, which you can buy via the [official Vatican Museums website](https://m.museivaticani.va/content/museivaticani-mobile/en/organizza-visita/tariffe-e-biglietti.html)

Comment: Don't buy skip-the-line tickets. They're a scam. (They're real tickets, but massively marked up, and when you get to the museum, there'll be no line to skip.)

Comment: @A.R. There are no tickets present in the official website, they are all sold out. What about if my tickets are reserved for a particular time?

Comment: @Traveller, post answers, not comments. This comment is likely to be deleted some time soon.